# AWS classic load balancer not seeing instances with only private IP addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have setup an internet facing classic load balancer and when I provision an EC2 instance with a public IP address the load balancer can do the health check successfully but if I provision an identical instance without a public IP address the health check always fails. Everything is the same apart from not adding a public IP address. Same subnet, security groups, NACL etc.

The health check is TCP 80 ping. I have a web server on all instances and LB is listening on port 80.

Any ideas why it could be failing?

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-load-balancer-private-ec2/.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The instance without a public IP is failing to download and install the web server (httpd) so that is why the TCP 80 ping is failing. To access the web I need to use a NAT gateway or put a public IP on it.

curl -I  80 will show you if your web server is listening on that port.

Comment: Or simply include httpd in the AMI that you launch from.